# Access an web application APIs on a SSL enabled Tomcat programmatically in Spring

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-rest

I set up SSL on a Tomcat where both http on the port 8080 and https on the port 8443 are accessible directly, which I get the desired response from the application APIs. When I use the following Spring code to access the same APIs, I get NULL, however.

```
Foo mc = restTemplate.getForObject("http://" + hostName + ":8080" + "/foo" , Foo.class);
```

The code work when the SSL isn't set up.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get it works. For a benefit of others, I list the steps as the followings.

First, I add the code from The Spring RestTemplate with SSL (HttpClient 4.4) section of [this tutoiral](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl). (I have HttpClient 4.5.4). With this change, I get the following exception when I hit a URL of a Rest API:

```
I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/foo": 
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
  PKIX path building failed: 
  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
  unable to find valid certification path to requested target; 
  nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
  PKIX path building failed: 
  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
  unable to find valid certification path to requested targe
```

Second, to resolve the exception mentioned above, I follow the mkyong's [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/). BTW, the link of the Java program isn't valid anymore. I need to find it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure RestTemplate for HTTPS

Here is an example of what a test might look like for your case

```
@Test
public void httpsTest() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory  = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) requestFactory.getHttpClient();
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(acceptingTrustStrategy, 
        ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry()
        .register(new Scheme("https", 8443, sf));

    String urlOverHttps = "https://" + hostName + ":8080" + "/foo";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate(requestFactory).
      exchange(urlOverHttps, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode().value(), equalTo(200));
}
```

Comment: Your sample code is one of the situations mentioned in the article http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl . I get an error, "unable to find valid certification path to requested target". More things need to be done.